# Set of n variables($A_1,A_2,... A_n$) are linearly independent. Prove that ($A_1^t,A_2^t,... A_n^t$) is also linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have n square matrices $A_1,A_2...A_n$ that are linearly independent.Prove that the set $A_1^t,A_2^t..A_n^t$ are also linearly independent

Comment: What do you mean by "variables"? And what is the $^t$ denoting? Likely some vectors or matrices  and it's transposition but some clarity would help. You can [edit] your post. // Thinking about it, it could be an actual exponentiation and you want to show $t$-th powers of linearly independent elements are independent, but in which ambient structure?

Comment: Given your other comment, the $A_1$ is an element of what? Is it a matrix, a polynomial, something else? Honestly though, since you tagged it linear algebra, are your **certain** it is not the matrix transpose?

Comment: @quid It is a square matrix

Comment: It is clear to me that whoever wrote the problem meant ${}^t$ to mean the transpose.  Under any reasonable conditions on the $A_i$, the alternate statement involving $t \in \Bbb N$ is false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose they are not linearly independent so that there exist scalars $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$ (not all $0$) such that 
$$\alpha_1A_1^t+\cdots+\alpha_nA_n^t=0.$$
What happens if you apply the transpose operation to each side of the equation?

Edit: If $t$ denotes a natural power and not transpose, then the statement is false. The set $$\left\{\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix}\right\}$$ is a counterexample in the case of $t=2$.

Comment: What do you mean by transpose?

Comment: @user3600483 what do you meant by $^t$?

Comment: @quid raised to power of t. t is a natural number

Comment: @user3600483 Then the statement is not true in general. If we consider the vector space $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ and the linearly independent set $\left\{\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 0&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix}\right\}$, then the square of both elements is $0$ and hence the resulting vectors are not linearly independent. If I'm interpreting this incorrectly please elaborate on what exactly you're asking.

Comment: I am asking for proof of the statement.

Comment: It's false. I gave you a counterexample in the case of $t=2$. I'll edit my answer to reflect your updated question.